# Show Static text in Menu bar

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, view

I want to show a Users name in the menu bar after they log in.  Currently it is showing up but it is aligned to the top and faded (compared to the rest).

Here is my html for it:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    @if (Session["LoggedUserID"] != null)
    {
        <li>
            @Html.DisplayName(Session["LoggedUserFullName"].ToString())
        </li>
    }
```

If you look in the picture below, you can barely see my name in the upper right hand corner.

[image: Picture not displaying correctly]

Here is the Html that is being generated:

```
</ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
            Daniel Blois
        </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Do you have an idea of what HTML is being generated? Why do you need to use `@Html.DisplayName`? Try just using `@(Session["LoggedUserFullName"]).ToString()`

Comment: I tried it like that too and I had the same result.  I added the @html.DisplayName to try something different.

Comment: Added the generated html to the original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference the bootstrap docs for [navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar).

Since this is just text and not a link, use `navbar-text`:

```
<p class="navbar-text navbar-right">@Html.DisplayName(Session["LoggedUserFullName"].ToString())</p>
```

If you do this, get rid of your surrounding `<ul>` as well.

Or if you want it to be a link, you can keep what you have and add an `<a>` tag:

```
<li>
    <a href="#">@Html.DisplayName(Session["LoggedUserFullName"].ToString())</a>
</li>
```